# Bootstrap:columns stacking horizontally

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using 3 columns inside a nested row.
instead of stacking horizontally columns are  stacking vertically.
this is my code.
i have tried `stackoverflow` answers but not working.

```
  <div class="jumbotron mainBar">
      <div class="container mainBarContainer">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-2">
                 <div class=" profilePic">
                  <a href="#section_1"><h2>1<small>st</small><p>Title</p></h2></a>
                 </div>

                </div>
              <div class="col-xs-4">
                 <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-6 container">
                <div class="row">
                 <div clas="col-xs-4">
                  <div class=" profilePic1">
                   <a href="#section_1"><h2>1<small>st</small><p>Title</p></h2></a>
                  </div>
                 </div>
                 <div clas="col-xs-4">
                  <div class=" profilePic1">
                   <a href="#section_1"><h2>1<small>st</small><p>Title</p></h2></a>
                  </div>
                 </div>
                 <div clas="col-xs-4">
                  <div class=" profilePic1">
                   <a href="#section_1"><h2>1<small>st</small><p>Title</p></h2></a>
                  </div>
                 </div>
                </div>

              </div>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

and here is the fiddle
[fiidle](http://jsfiddle.net/3uzuf2j7/13/)

Comment: You question is not so clear. describe more. I think problem is container class with col-xs-6

Comment: I just want the 1st column 2nd column ,3rd column horizontally. but now it is stacking vertically.if u look the fiddle u wil get

Comment: Remove the container class which is with col-xs-6

Comment: Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3uzuf2j7/16/. You had a type error on `class` atrribute for `col-xs-4` elements (` <div clas="col-xs-4">` should be  `<div class="col-xs-4">`).

Comment: Nice one Jahan, I didnt notice the container class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a spieling mistake. Change the `clas` to `class` which is inside second container.

The  [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sarowerj/3uzuf2j7/18/)